# How can i make multiple divs to scroll up,down,right and left

Tags: jquery, html

I wanted a container with multiple divs to move up, down, left and right using arrows in jquery, it would be glad if anyone provide a fiddle for this

Comment: Please add your attempt so far

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

It is currently the most used plugin for this kind of sites.
Works in modern and old browsers, touch devices and has a good respond to kinetic scrolling in Apple laptops.
It deals with URL hashes, returning links (anchor links), resizing...

Plenty of configurable options, methods and callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for this, but my divs are basically 300X300 and lies within the section, so around it i need the arrows to navigate (up/down/left/right)